# r replace variable name in script

Tags: r

I want to replace all the names of a specific variable in my script (such as the shift + enter in matlab).
For exemple in the R script I could have:

```
var <- 1 + 2
var2 <- var * 5
```

That I want to change to :

```
var1 <- 1 + 2
var2 <- var1 * 5
```

The point is to avoid the "search an replace" that would have change the second variable in`var12`.

Comment: still search and replace using "whole word" option ?

Comment: Thanks, still if you have the whole name in a comment for exemple, it will be switched. I wonder why their is not a shortcut as in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `var(?![1:9])` and replace with `var1`. Use regex search. The regex asserts that only var is matched which is not followed by any number.

Comment: Thanks, this is an option. I'm still looking for the same shortcut as in matlab but it is useful thank you.